# Can't deploy Rails app with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, linode

Hi I am using Linode server. I done all the config and installed Capistrano and included that gem in Gemfile. Also done with deploy script. But i am getting following error , when trying to run "cap deploy".

I am very new to rails.if some one can help it will be useful.

[image]

CAP FilE :

[image]

Deploy Script : 
[image]

I think some Ruby Version problem , but not sure. Using Ruby : 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Followed , this guide step by step its started working. Thanks for help :)

URL : http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the `rvm-capistrano` gem.

Try adding this to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
```

Comment: Thanks , I solved with the help of this guide : http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html